# Отправка лишних копий сообщения при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть кнопка, которая открывает и закрывает чат, а прикол в том, что сколько раз ты открыл и закрыл чат, столько копий сообщений и отправиться потом)) Из-за чего может такое быть?

```
    $('#write_message').click(function(){
            $('.message_block').toggle();                 
            $('#chat_block').html('')
                .animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, 1100);
            getMessage();
            $('#send_message').click(function(){
                data={message:$('#message').val(), id:id, action:'send_message'};
                $.post('core.php', data, function (response) {
                    if(response == 1){
                        $('#message').val('');
                        getMessage();
                        setInterval(getMessage, 5000);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы определили в одном обработчике click, другой обработчик click - сколько раз нажмете кнопку первого обработчика, столько обработчиков навесится на второй элемент. Нужно вынести второй обработчик за пределы первого. Используйте вместо click(), метод on() и навешивайте обработчик не на сам элемент, а на документ (так обработчик будет работать не зависимо от того, был элемент на странице на момент объявления или появился после).

Comment: спасибо вам добрый человек )!